# How can I delete a Exception handler?

Tags: java, exception

I want to delete the exception handler from this code because I dont understand the reason it is there, and I believe it does not do anything in the stage of my code. 
I have this:

```
public void ToFile(){
               try{
                   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));

                    for (String st:stringarray){ 
                          pw.println(st);
                          pw.close();
                            }
                    }catch(Exception exception)
                    {}
            }
```

When I delete the exception part, I transform it into this, but it gives me error...:

```
public void ToFile(){

                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter();
                            for (String st:items){ 
                                    pw.println(srtingarray);
                                    pw.close();
                            }

            }
```

What should I do ?
**EDIT
ERROR:** no suitable constructor found for PrintWriter.

Comment: handling exceptions is a good practice. Why you want to delete that code?

Comment: can you supply the error stack?

Comment: You seem to have removed some arguments from your `PrintWriter.__construct()` call.

Comment: Agrees with @Sushil: you don't want to get rid of the handler -- you want to catch and deal with exceptions, and most important fix the errors that it is finding!!! You're going about things all wrong.

Comment: Sushil - While handling exceptions can be good practice, catching and ignoring exception is terrible practice.

Comment: _What error do you get_?

Comment: `"What should I do ? EDIT ERROR: no suitable constructor found for PrintWriter."` I'd look at the PrintWriter API and use only a proper constructor. You will want to go through the exception tutorials from the Java tutorials I'm thinking. You'll also want to hit the intro/basic tutorials as well.

Comment: @JacobM i agree with you. He must do something to handle the exception

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels because I dont understand exactly what exceptions do, I want to delete them.

Comment: I can't see any reason why one calls close() method several time. Exception will be always thrown any time `st` have more than one element. That's very strange code.

Comment: `"because I dont understand exactly what exceptions do, I want to delete them."` This is kind of equivalent to going to a car mechanic and saying, "I don't know how to use the breaks on my car. Can you remove them?" The answer is to learn how to use your breaks (exceptions). Please go to [this link to the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) and search for the exceptions section.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What if your brakes break?

Comment: @pst: Then you may be SOL. Next time make sure that your car has been unit tested.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
public void toFile() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));

    for (String str: items){ 
        pw.println(str);
    }

    pw.close();
}
```

Using a `PrintWriter` can generate `IOException`s when writing fails. You can either catch and handle those in your function, or add a `throws` clause which allows the exception to propagate upwards to the caller.

(I've also moved the `close()` call outside of the loop and fixed up how you use `pw`.)

Know that adding a `throws` clause doesn't solve your problem exactly as the caller will still need to handle the exception. It just moves the problem up one level. It's the right thing to do, though. 
There's no way to completely ignore an `IOException`. These functions can error out, and Java forces you to handle these errors at some point or another. This is a **good thing**.

If you'd rather handle the exception here, you can do that. And it's a good idea to do *something* in the `catch` clause. Seeing `catch(Exception e) { }` with an empty handler makes baby Knuth sad.

```
public void toFile() {
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));

        for (String str: items){ 
            pw.println(str);
        }

        pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How should I call ToFile from the main now? I make and object `MyObject` and after I write `MyObject.ToFile();` and it tells me that I didnt hundle the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The exception handler was "handling"<sup>1</sup> the IOException that might be thrown by `new FileWriter(file, false)` when the file could not be opened.  If you are not going to handle it, you must declare it in the method signature:

```
public void toFile() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));
    for (String st : items) { 
        pw.println(st);
    }
    pw.close();
}
```

I've also taken the opportunity to fix the method name.  Never start a method name with a capital letter.  It is a major style error.

And I fixed another 2 compilation errors and a bug.  (See if you can spot it ... and figure out why it was a bug.)

Finally, the **really** correct way to write this is:

```
// Java 7
public void toFile() throws IOException {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false))) {
        for (String st : items) { 
            pw.println(st);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
// pre-Java 7
public void toFile() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false))) {
    try {
        for (String st : items) { 
            pw.println(st);
        }
    } finally {
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

You need to do this so that the `FileWriter` always gets closed ... even when an unexpected exception is thrown in the loop.

---

<sup>1 - In fact, the original `catch (Exception exception) { }` was truly terrible.  Firstly, it was just gobbling up the exception without saying anything.  Secondly, it was doing it for `Exception` ... and that includes a whole bunch of exceptions like `NullPointerException` that would most likely be evidence of a bug.  Don't squash exceptions, and particularly don't try to "handle" `Exception` like that.</sup>

Comment: Good point on properly closing the writer. I left that out of my answer, I'm glad it's in yours.

Comment: How should I call ToFile from the main now? I make and object MyObject and after I write MyObject.ToFile(); and it tells me that I didnt hundle the exception.

Comment: @georgemano - You need to handle the exception in `main` ...  or declare `main` as `throws IOExcption`.  But before you do that, PLEASE read Oracle's Java tutorials.  You will save yourself a lot of time and aggravation in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception is that after the first iteration of the loop you are closing the PrintWriter object.